# How to remove the login panel that appears when opening Web AppBuilder application

Tags: gis, portal

I created a Web AppBuilder application, and my featurelayers and webmap are shared with organization in ArcGIS portal. And each time the application opens it asks for login to access the portal which gives a 60 minute token, but is there a way to remove the login completely for when the application is published? In the GISPortal i have the share option set on Everyone and it still doesn't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A login popup will open if you have any layer with protected access in your webmap, created with Arcgis Portal. One way to identify what layer is responsible for opening the login popup is to load your web appbuilder application with the developer tools opened. A console error is thrown when you try to acess a protected layer and then the popup will open so that you can put your username and password. You can identify in the developer tools network panel what request was responsible for that.

I've experienced some time ago a case where a layer was shared with Everyone in Arcgis Portal, but having a behaviour like it was not shared. After I unshared it in Arcgis Portal, and shared it again, the problem was solved.

Another place to check is the root config.json file of you web appbuilder application. I think a login popup will open too if you have a protected url configured in the "geometryService" property.